# Using dynamic SQL with Unpivot to replace column names

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need a bit of help. Have been bashing my head how to this all morning and don't have much of a progress. I have been trying to do some dynamic Unpivots but I am new to the concept and cannot make it work.

I have a table with many columns where the values of the columns have different meaning based on one other field in the table. The meaning can be checked by joining on a second table.
For example the Main table is like

```
UniqueID    Trade_Type  date_parm01 date_parm02
1           A           27/04/2016  28/04/2016
2           A           27/04/2016  28/04/2016
3           B           27/04/2016  28/04/2016
4           B           27/04/2016  28/04/2016
5           B           27/04/2016  28/04/2016
```

The column name explain table is like

```
Trade_Type  Column Name_Main_Table  Column_Name_NEW
A           date_parm01             Start_Date
A           date_parm02             End_Date
B           date_parm01             Other_Date
B           date_parm02             Other_Date2
```

And I need to replace the non descript column names in the main table with the descriptive names from the explain table

```
UniqueID    Trade_Type  Start_Date  End_Date    Other_Date  Other_Date2
1           A           27/04/2016  28/04/2016      
2           A           27/04/2016  28/04/2016      
3           B                                   27/04/2016  28/04/2016
4           B                                   27/04/2016  28/04/2016
5           B                                   27/04/2016  28/04/2016
```

The table has over 200 columns and over 70 trade types so this would make the total columns in new table something like 14000

I would then need a select query that dynamically only selects the columns that apply for each trade type once I specify the trade type in the query.

Comment: Please post the query you tried, and what error or unexpected results you got.   Right now you have the background for a question, but you have not yet posted a question.

Comment: You just need to collect all the column names you have from the explain table for the columns of the pivot, and also join the table with your data to get the column names there too for the pivot -- and this of course needs to be dynamic SQL, assuming you don't have a fixed number of columns you can use.